# Simplify expression F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I want the expression (x-x) to be simplified to 0.

```
type aexpr = 
| CstI of int
| Var of string
| Add of aexpr * aexpr
| Sub of aexpr * aexpr
| Mul of aexpr * aexpr;;

let rec simplify expr =
match expr with
| Add(CstI(n1), CstI(n2)) ->CstI(n1 + n2)
| Sub(CstI(n1), CstI(n2)) ->CstI(n1 - n2)
| Mul(CstI(n1), CstI(n2)) ->CstI(n1 * n2)
| Add(e, CstI(0)) -> simplify e
| Add(CstI(0), e) -> simplify e
| Sub(CstI(0), e) -> simplify e
| Sub(e, CstI(0)) -> simplify e
| Sub(Var(x1), Var(x2)) when x1.Equals(x2) -> CstI(0) // <- not working
| Mul(CstI(0), e) -> CstI(0)
| Mul(e, CstI(0)) -> CstI(0)
| Mul(CstI(1), e) -> simplify e
| Mul(e, CstI(1)) -> simplify e
| _ -> expr;;
```

This does not do it. I do not see what I am doing wrong. Hope you can help me :)

**Edit:**
It compiles fine but it does not do anything. Ie.

```
let e = Mul(CstI(1), Add(CstI(4), Sub(Var("x"), Var("x"))));;
```

In f# interactive:

```
let result = simplify e;;
val result : aexpr = Add (CstI 4,Sub (Var "x",Var "x"))
```

Result should be `CstI 4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`simplify (Sub (Var "x", Var "x"))` works just fine. The reason that your example does not work is that `simplify` does not traverse the whole tree, so the `Sub (Var "x", Var "x")` part of the tree is never simplified.

In short, you're missing a case `Sub (e,e) -> Sub (simplify e, simplify e)` and the same for the other operators.

Comment: Note that even with this change, you might need to run multiple passes to get a fully simplified result.  E.g. you ultimately would like to reduce `Sub(CstI 5, Add(CstI 1, CstI 2))` not just to `Sub(CstI 5, CstI 3)`, but all the way to `CstI 2`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work here. You're not dealing with a case-sensitivity issue with the string comparison, are you?